# Paypal webhook instead of return url

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

Here is my flow of the payment.

1. Create Payment and return Url for user to verify
2. Using above Url user opens Paypal account and accepts payment
3. After accepting payment Paypal returns to success url.
4. Execute payment (final stage of the sale)

My Question is if there exists any webhook triggered after `step 2`, before `step 3`. Right after user verifies payment in it's personal paypal page.

The reason to catch webhook is not to rely on success redirect url rather than use webhook.

Answer (score 0):

The terms you are using do not match the keywords you've used here.

Are you working with REST APIs or are you working with PayPal Standard / Classic APIs?

If you're working with REST APIs, then the simple answer is yes, you should use the Webhooks to handle any automated processing.  Specifically, take a look at the [SALE Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/#sales).  That should give you what you're after.

If you're working with Standard / Classic, the answer is the same except that you would use IPN instead of Webhooks.

Comment: Using rest api, but was not able to find corresponding webhook which I described above.

Comment: I updated the answer.  I believe what you want is PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED

Comment: PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED triggers  after execution of the payment, after section 4 described in my question

Comment: Which is when it would be logical to make any updates necessary.